# How to do Conditionals in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing, cypress-conditional-testing

In my e2e, I need to check if the datatable is populated first before before checkboxes in the table are clicked.

I am able to check the count like so

```
cy.get('.p-datatable-table').find('tr').its('length').should('be.gte', 0);
```

unfortunately, the below does not work.

```
  if (cy.get('.p-datatable-table').find('tr').its('length').should('be.gte', 0)) {
    cy.get('.select-all-boxes').click();
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In Cypress, commands do not return their subjects, instead yield them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the expression `cy.get('.p-datatable-table').find('tr').its('length').should('be.gte', 0)` to perform an if check.

The result of that expression is a chainable, so you have to chain it

```js
cy.get('.p-datatable-table').find('tr').its('length')
  .then(length => {
    if ( length ) {
      cy.get('.select-all-boxes').click()
    }
  })
```

Not sure what you expect with `.should('be.gte', 0)` but it does nothing so I dropped it.